# Why can't I get sound to my TV using an HDMI-to-DVI cable?

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi, dvi, tv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does DVI carry audio?](https://superuser.com/questions/188568/does-dvi-carry-audio)

I've got an Acer eMachine running Windows 7 64-bit and I'm hooking it up to my TV using an HDMI-to-DVI cable. Obviously, the HDMI end of the cable is plugged into my laptop and the DVI end of the cable into the TV. I've got a beautiful picture but any and all sounds come out of the speakers on my laptop. I've tried going into Control Panel -> Sounds and clicking "Show hidden devices", but the only thing that pops up is an old TV I hooked up with a normal HDMI cable. Anyone know why I can't get sound through my TV?

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is that DVI doesn't do sound, and HDMI does.

Does your TV support HDMI?  Then you should just use a straight HDMI cable.

Does your laptop have an audio-out port?  If the laptop has a headphone jack and the TV has RCA inputs you could get a 3.5mm to RCA cable and use that to connect them, then you should get the laptop sound out of the TV speakers.

RCA inputs look like this:

[image: RCA inputs]

Answer (score 2):

DVI doesn't carry audio.

- DVI = Digital *Visual* Interface ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface))
- HDMI = High-Definition *Multimedia* Interface ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdmi))

You'll need to run separate lines for audio.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, HDMI cables carry the Video and Audio signal, and DVI cables just conduct Video.

Take a look:

> HDMI supports the transport of packets, needed for digital audio, in addition to digital video. 
>   (source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#DVI_and_HDMI_compatibility )

and also [does-dvi-carry-audio-signals-as-well-as-video](http://www.cnet.com.au/does-dvi-carry-audio-signals-as-well-as-video-339270821.htm)